# ColdFusion inheritance check

Tags: inheritance, reflection, coldfusion

How can I check if one java object extends another java object with ColdFusion?

```
<cffunction name="render" access="public" returntype="void" output="true">
    <cfargument name="page" type="any" required="true" />
    <cfset var model = arguments.page.getModel() />


    <cfif <!--- model extends SpecialBaseModel ---> >
        <!--- Do Something --->
    </cfif>

</cffunction>
```

The java object in question has not been created with `createObject` nor `cf_object`.  And I only have the namespace and classname of the extended class, not an actual instance nor a  Class object that represent this class.

Comment: If you need to write your code this way, I suspect you might have some issues with your domain model, or at least the inheritance in {{Model}} and {{SpecialBaseModel}}. What sort of thing are you then doing inside the {{if}} block?

Comment: I'm just rendering a link if the model is of a special type.

Answer (score 2):

didn't you search cf docs?

here you go: http://cfdocs.org/isinstanceof

There're also http://cfdocs.org/cachegetmetadata and http://cfdocs.org/getcomponentmetadata if you want to go crazy with reflection.

Comment: `IsInstanceOf` was not working for me.  I think this is because the object in question is a Java object that was not created with the `CreateObject` method nor the `cf_object` tag.

Comment: How was it created? IIRC, IsInstanceOf is class loader sensitive. So it might fail for java objects created with a *different* class loader than the main CF bootstrap class loader.

Comment: @Leigh, I think that is what's happening.  I think the two objects are being created with different class loaders.

Comment: @StevenWexler - Possibly, but you still did not tell us how you are creating the objects ;-) Can you update your question with a simple example that reproduces the issue?  We need a concrete example to offer further advice.